# Regex to replace padding-right but only in td tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

Could anyone point me in the right direction to replace only the padding right attribute within a td tag ? I have to use regex and cannot use html agility pack or any other tools. The source is an http fragment. I have tried anything as I'm a bit lost. Can't post samples as I'm on my phone. Many thanks.

Comment: So a css attribute in a style attrib? You can always override it elsewhere or just replace with `-x-fake`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that matches `padding-right` Only within `td`. Note,that this matches only within the `td` tag itself, not between `<td>` and `</td>`

```
(<td [^>]+)padding-right *:[^;"]+ *;?
```

You can replace the above by the first capture group to remove all `padding-right` from td tags

[example](http://rubular.com/r/Mv3dBgnNiB)

To match `padding-right` in between the tags, use:

```
(<td.*?>.*?)padding-right *:[^;"]+ *;?(.*?)(?=<\/td>)
```

(Assumes same line)

[example](http://rubular.com/r/cGgDirkk1S)

Comment: Thank you. Regex continues to cuddle my mind. I'll test your code when I get chance.

Comment: What will this do to `<td x="padding-right:3;" no-padding-right:3>`?  What should it do?

Comment: What I need to do is change <td style="padding-right: 0 ... To <td style="padding-right: 2 ... Padding-right could appear anywhere in the attribute list.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I doubt one would ever write html like that, but since it's still in the realm of possibility, this should do: http://rubular.com/r/S8fC0ZFjm9

Comment: @bhs: In that case, use `(<td [^>]*style="[^"]*)padding-right *: *0 *;` and replace with `\1padding-right:3;`. Example: http://rubular.com/r/cEQc5nTc82

Comment: @rado apologies for the delay - the fix never got used as it turned out to the document type that was at fault - thanks for your help and comments though

Answer (score 1):

Give up.

Unless you have some strict rules that your HTML follows, you can't use a regex for this (which is why there are parsers).  For example, the attribute you are looking could appear somewhere else in the tag, so your regex couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: Love this answer. I wish I could but am unable to use third party tools, so no parsers.

Comment: What about the parser built into Javascript?

Comment: @ScottHunter Can you provide a sample usage?